# In a multiplayer game, who can see a player's revealed hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a player reveals their hand in a multiplayer game, does everyone get to look at the player's hand, or only the controller of the ability that forced them to reveal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You reveal the card to all players.

> 701.13. Reveal
>
> 701.13a To reveal a card, show that card **to all players** for a brief time. If an effect causes a card to be revealed, it remains revealed for as long as necessary to complete the parts of the effect that card is relevant to. If the cost to cast a spell or activate an ability includes revealing a card, the card remains revealed from the time the spell or ability is announced until the time it leaves the stack.

Comment: In case it ever matters, you generally should ask if someone is "done looking" before putting the card away.  You can't keep an opponent from writing down your hand by flashing your cards in front of their face for 5 seconds and then declaring "Well I showed you!"  Don't be that guy.

Comment: @EthanTheBrave I think you are half correct. If you cast Wanderwine Hub and reveal a Merfolk card, then you have to give me time to inspect the card. However, if I resolve Thoughtseize, inspect your hand for two seconds, and then choose a card, then by my interpretation of 701.13a you can immediately stop revealing your hand. At casual or Regular REL, I expect that you will be gracious enough to allow me to keep looking. At Competitive REL, I made a sloppy play and that's that.

Comment: you are correct! I forgot about that.  If they need to look to complete an action, by completing the action they make it so you no longer need to reveal.